# Excel Code not running when edits are made

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get my spreadsheet to update when an edit is made in row "L" but for some reason when I edit the cells within my range nothing changes, it was working perfectly before but now it doesn't

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L100:L200")) Is Nothing Then
    Call CopyDataTesting

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong. [Column I am trying to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVLt6.png) on successful macro run, the Pass or Fail should become all capitalized

Edit: Here is the CopyTestData Code:

```
Sub CopyDataTesting()
    Dim c As Range
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    For Each c In Range("L1:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        SN = c.Offset(0, -3).Value
        
        If c = "Fail" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            c.EntireRow.Copy
            c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            c.Select
            c.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
            c.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Value = "FAIL"
            c.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf c = "Pass" Then
            c.Value = "PASS"
            
            c.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206)
            c.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206)
            c.Offset(0, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206)
            c.Offset(0, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 202, 237)
            c.Offset(0, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 202, 237)
            c.Offset(0, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 202, 237)
            
                    
        End If
       
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Edit 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L1:L1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Call CopyDataTesting
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("R1:R100")) Is Nothing Then
        Call CopyDataFinal 'Assume that this macro and the CopyDataTesting function similarly

    End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely an error occurred, and `Application.EnableEvents = True` never ran, so your events are disabled.

Comment: Could you share the `CopyDataTesting` procedure?

Comment: I added in the code, and also what kind of error would occur? There was no error that popped up when I run it

Comment: Is `CopyDataTesting` in the worksheet code module?  If not, you should specify an explicit worksheet qualifier for `Range("L1:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: Your event handler only looks at L100:L200 but `CopyDataTesting` looks from L1 and down...

Comment: The thing is the code was working perfectly fine before and it was updating after edits, I'm just not sure why it broke suddenly, the `CopyDataTesting` is a module. I changed L100:L200 to match the other sheet and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note it's good practice to add error handling whenever you turn off events, to make sure they get re-enabled before your code exits.

Also the event code can determine exactly which cells in Col L were changed and pass that range to `CopyDataTesting`, so there's no need to scan the whole column each time.

This works fine for me:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L1:L1000"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        CopyDataTesting rng 'pass the changed cells to `CopyDatatesting`
    End If
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("R1:R1000"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        CopyDataFinal rng  'pass the changed cells to `CopyDataFinal`
    End If
    
haveError:
    'ensure events are re-enabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub CopyDataFinal(rng As Range)
    'add your code here
End Sub

Sub CopyDataTesting(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, SN
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        SN = c.Offset(0, -3).Value  '<<<<< what is this for?
        If c = "Fail" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            c.EntireRow.Offset(1).Value = c.EntireRow.Value
            c.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
            c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            c.Value = "FAIL"
        ElseIf c = "Pass" Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206)
            c.Offset(0, 5).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(240, 202, 237)
            c.Value = "PASS"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! If I wanted to add two more columns that the macro needs to read how would I do that?

Comment: That's a bit vague so I'm not sure how to answer - if you edit your question to add details I will try to adjust the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73547518/edit

Comment: Updated the question, let me know if that makes a bit more sense

Comment: See updated code above

Comment: It worked for a bit, then I tried changing the range from (L1:L1000) to (L1:L2000) then it's not working anymore. Any idea why?

Comment: Try commenting out `On Error GoTo haveError` and see if you're getting any errors.  Don't forget you may need to re-enable events if you code exits before `Application.EnableEvents = True` gets executed

Comment: I tried enabling events in different parts throughout the code and still get nothing. Also I don't get any errors. Still don't really understand how it worked before and it doesn't work now.  I changed back to (L1:L1000) and it still doesn't work

Comment: Are events turned on?  If you put a breakpoint on (eg) `Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L1:L1000"))` does the code break there when you change a cell in that range?

Comment: Yes events are on, and the code doesn't break when I change cells in the range

Comment: Sorry there's no way for me to debug that kind of situation.  I can help if you can share the workbook (with the minimal amount of relevant code).  You could try moving the code to a new workbook and see if it works there.

Comment: I can do that, I couldn't find a way to attach in on this chain, can I send it by email? Thanks so much for your help, I've been struggling with this for so long